# Reading from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am reading from a text file and saving the lines into an `ArrayList`. But I have had no success in how to go through and read all of the specific characters in the `ArrayList`, how many columns and rows there are.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
        String line;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r);
        ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            myArrayList.add(line);
            .........
        }
```

Comment: Traverse the `ArrayList` and get the info you want/need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading your post right you are wanting to **further break apart your lines** (your reference to columns). Since you are storing `String` objects **you will need to further break apart those entries into another** `List` to truly parse through your words and characters appropriately.

Java used to have something called the `StringTokenizer` which could do what you want but that is now deprecated and replaced by the [String.Split()](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs302/examples/Parsing/parseString.html) method. By iterating through your `ArrayList` and splitting the `String` Object by specific delimiters (such as a space or a period), you should be able to further breakdown your existing `ArrayList` and create a new List with individual words, or even characters.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling the `List` myArrayList, I think you want to change this

```
ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

to (using the [diamond operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html) and the interface type) -

```
List<String> store = new ArrayList<>(); // <-- match the name.
```

You can count the "rows" by getting the size of the `List` -

```
int rows = store.size();
```

To count "columns" you would need to iterate the List and examine the lines. (or you could do that while you read the input) -

```
for (String line : store) {
  // count columns in line
}
```

Comment: I would count the *columns* while reading the file, not from the `List`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I did mentioned that in the parenthetical *or you could do that while you read the input*

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you use "store.add(line)". You should use myArrayList instead of this.
After you have stored everything in the ArrayList you can use a for-each loop to traverse through the list:

```
for (String string : myArrayList) {
    // do everything with the strings here
}
```

Comment: Yes, it has been edited. But I'm not just interested in the strings but in every character in the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go through a `ArrayList` there are many ways that you can try
You can easily get number of elements in the `ArrayList` using `size()` method.

e.g.

```
//traditional way
for(int i = 0; i< arrayList.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(arrayList.get(i));
}

//enhanced forloop
if your ArrayList is String type
for(String row : arrayList)
    System.out.println(row);
```

With Java 8 you cane have more easier iterator that can use to go through the ArrayList

Edited

If you wanna read character by character

```
for(String row : arrayList){
   char []letters = row/toCharArray();
   for(char character : letters)
       System.out.print(character + " ") ;
}
```

Comment: This loop gets the whole string in the arrayList. Let's say I have the 2 strings, Hello and Goodbye. I want to read each char and be able to retrieve that letter.

Comment: With the new code I get this printed out: "first string" "first and seconds string" "first second and third string".

Comment: so isnt it what you want?

Comment: Three strings, Hello, Goodbye and Potatoes. With your code I would get Hello \n Hello Goodbye \n Hello Goodbye Potatoes. What I want is to go through the list once, read the characters, compare for example if they are equals to "T" and so if I would print it all out it would say: Hello \n Goodbye \n Potatoes